# Cannot find module "postgraphile plugin upload field "

Tags: file-upload, postgraphile

i installed postgraphile-plugin-upload-field

npm i graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-upload-field

then

`postgraphile -c 'postgres://postgres:mysecretpass@192.168.38.4:5432/gimapp' --cors -p 5001 --enhance-graphiql --host "0.0.0.0" -s messages,basic_auth,user --append-plugins @graphile/postgis,@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector,postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter,@graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-upload-field --watch  --no-ignore-indexes --jwt-token-identifier basic_auth.jwt_token --jwt-secret mysecretpass`

throws exception like this.

```
Failed to load plugin '@graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-upload-field'
/usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/build/postgraphile/cli.js:268
            throw e;
            ^

Error: Cannot find module '@graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-upload-field'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/build/postgraphile/cli.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/build/postgraphile/cli.js:263:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at loadPlugins (/usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/build/postgraphile/cli.js:255:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/build/postgraphile/cli.js:323:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/build/postgraphile/cli.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/postgraphile/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

and here is another situation if i remove **@graphile-contrib**

`postgraphile -c 'postgres://postgres:mysecretpass@192.168.38.4:5432/gimapp' --cors -p 5001 --enhance-graphiql --host "0.0.0.0" -s messages,basic_auth,user --append-plugins @graphile/postgis,@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector,postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter,postgraphile-plugin-upload-field --watch  --no-ignore-indexes --jwt-token-identifier basic_auth.jwt_token --jwt-secret mysecretpass`

here is the error:

```
PostGraphile v4.10.0 server listening on port 5001 



Recoverable error occurred; use envvar 'DEBUG="graphile-build:warn"' for full error (see: https://graphile.org/postgraphile/debugging )
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined…
Recoverable error occurred; use envvar 'DEBUG="graphile-build:warn"' for full error (see: https://graphile.org/postgraphile/debugging )
```